# How to unit test this C# method which returns List of teams from an api?

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing

I want to unit test this C# method which returns List of teams from an api?Any Help?

```
public List<FootballTeam> LoadTeamStats(string seasonId)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = _footballApiClient.GetAsync($"{FootballApiUrls.GET_TEAMS_FOR_SEASON}/{seasonId}?api_token={ApiKeyValue}&include=stats:filter(season_id|{seasonId})").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string teamData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FootballTeamBySeasonQuery>(teamData);
        return ParseTeamDetailsFromApi(dto.Teams);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApiException(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: I want to test the Buisness logic. What situations should I test in this case?

Comment: There isn't any business logic there, except for perhaps `ParseTeamDetailsFromApi`. Is there a reason you want to unit test the controller method rather than `ParseTeamDetailsFromApi` directly?

Comment: You need to mock the external resources, such as the `API` to get the data from the `DB` part, use the interface to replace the implementation with abstraction,

Comment: The most important thing to write about `Unit-Test` is that you need to know which piece of code you want to test.

Comment: How should we know what your business-logic looks like? You didn´t provide any. Apart from this there´s no magic button or script for "create a unit-test to verify this method works as expected". Instead you should think yourself: define your use-cases for this method. This includes all possible input and the expected output. In your case you should write at least two tests: one for `response` with `IsSuccessStatusCode` being true and one for false. Then simply check if the return-value is what you expect in the first case or if it throws the exception in the latter.

Comment: A unit test does mock external components and test the logic. In your sample the http call should be considered an external component and you could only unit test the `parseTeamDetailsFromApi` function. If you want to test external components we are talking of other kind of tests.

Comment: It's not so clear, which cases would you like to test?

Comment: Thanks for all the useful stuff by u guys. Can u plz tell me how can I mock http request in the sample above or any references u would suggest to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could test here is `LoadTeamStats` method returns some expected data when `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is `true` and otherwise `LoadTeamStats` method throws the `ApiException`.

To test it you could mock `_footballApiClient`. But as we see `_footballApiClient` is `HttpClient` that can't be mocked easily, hence you need to hide it behind your own interface then mock it.

So write your own interface for `HttpClient` and mock it with one of mocking libs like [`Moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and then write the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all would suggest to separate concerns of this method. Leave all the HTTP / REST related functionality in your WebAPi controller actions but extract the logic itself into their own class. I normally call them business-service and I put them into my non-web-related assembly of the project (normally called `xyz.Core.dll`).

Check out the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of SOLID if this isn't familiar to you. Lesson I've learned: this makes unit-testing your logic (eg. query and parsing) way easier as you don't need to mock/fake `HttpRequest` etc. There are libraries that can mock this stuff too but it can get tricky quickly.

Then you can use any unit-testing framework for C# for writing tests for the logic like the new `TeamDataReader` and the `TeamDetailsParser` classes. Frameworks like [Nunit](https://nunit.org/), [XUnit](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111223135/https://xunit.github.io/) or [MSTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest) will do a good job here. I can also recommend the Fake-Library [FakeItEasy](https://fakeiteasy.github.io) and the [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com) library.